# Get Count of not null items in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to know how to get a count of not null items in a row. As an example, if someone answers to question 1 to 5 and leave other 5 then answer should be 5. Can I know how to do it in the row?

This is my query

```
$qs = Question::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

[image: This is the output]
I want to get out of that null columns. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Reveal your code so that we understand it in better way. Or else you can simple check for null values with the built in is_null function

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array with any looping mechanism alongside the variable for tracking the count,e.g. while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native function or not.
but I want to write a good helper code:

```
$answer_count=[];
foreach ($rows as $row){

    $count=0;

    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        if($value!==null && startWith($key, 'answer')) {
             $count+=1;
        }   
    }

    $answer_count[] = ['id' => $row['id'],
            'count' => $count,
        ];
}
```

Comment: In one row have 10 questions and if some fill five questions and leave the other five, I want to calculate that filled five. Because I will give them some points to that answered questions.

Comment: it just needs to replace `'answer'` with your question's column names: 'answer_1' , 'answer_2' ... it's ok with my code

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the function getAttributes() to get your model 's attributes
and use the filter to filter them:

```
$nullAttributesCount=collect($qs->getAttributes()) ->filter(function ($value, $key)
            {
            return $value===null;}
            )->count();
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you help me with this? Your answer is not got any output.

Comment: strange .. i usually test my answer before committing them, please try again carefully